# UIButton font not smooth

Tags: ios, uibutton

I add some UIButton to the view, but the font in the button seems not smooth(in retina screen)....

See the image:[image]

anyone help? Thanks!

Here is the method I adding the buttons:

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items {
    if (_items != items) {
        _items = items;
        for (UIView *v in self.containerView.subviews) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
        int i = 1;
        CGFloat y = 8;
        for (id item in _items) {
            UIButton *itemButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            itemButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.containerView.bounds.size.width, 35);
            itemButton.tag = i;
            [itemButton setTitle:item forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [itemButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [itemButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            itemButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
            [itemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            y += 35;
            [self.containerView addSubview:itemButton];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the button and adding / drawing the text?

Comment: Is the screenshot showing one button? I'm not clear on the loop or the size of a button.

Comment: There is three button on the screen.

Comment: what is the dimensions of image you have put in a view and have you added the correct fame size as the image has ?

Comment: @dark I just used one image, bg.png...

Comment: @YozoneW.  [self.view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView sizeToFit];
    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 1):

The problem resolved:

```
self.containerView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
if ([mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    self.containerView.contentScaleFactor = mainScreen.scale;
}
```

**self.containerView.contentScaleFactor = mainScreen.scale;**